# Different behavior on Android vs standard java

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In standard java this code works fine. But I think it shouldn't.

```
class Data{
private String name;

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
}
}

class Test{

private Data mData;

public void back(){
    mData=new Data();
    mData.setName("You");

}

public void go(){

    Thread mThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            System.out.println(mData.getName());
        }
    };
    mThread.start();
}
}
```

But when doing a similar thing in Android, it throws a NullPointerException.

```
private void writeApp(){
    Thread mThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            Log.d(TAG,modelData.getAppName());

        }
    };
    mThread.start();
}
```

//Edit

```
public void appOpens(String appPackageName) throws NameNotFoundException{

    modelData = new ModelData();
    modelData.setOpen(true);
    modelData.setAppPackageName(appPackageName);
    modelData.setOpenTime(getTimeMil());
    setAppNameAndAppVersion();
    }

private void writeApp(){
    Log.d(TAG+1,modelData.getAppName());//works fine
    Thread mThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            Log.d(TAG+2,modelData.getAppName());//doenst works throws NullPointerException
        }
    };
    mThread.start();
}
```

`appOpens(String appPackageName)` calling fist.
`Log.d(TAG+1,modelData.getAppName())` doesn't throw NullPointerException , but `Log.d(TAG+2,modelData.getAppName())` throws i believe it is proper behavior , cuz i don't share instance to thread.It is only reachable from main thread.But in standard java second thread accesses my main thread , how could it be?

Comment: Where does it throw the exception? What is null?

Comment: Log.d(TAG,modelData.getAppName());

Comment: Looks like *modelData* is not initialized. Where do you initialize *modelData*?

Comment: modelDAta is initialized properly i am sure i access getAppName() method outside from the thread.But in thread i cant.i think it is the proper behavior .In standart java how could it be reach an other threads mutable , because i do not send the instance to the thread.Isn't it imposible ? And i ececute back() first.

Comment: That's not possible. modelData must be null. Maybe you have two instances, and only one is initialized? Without seeing more relevant code, we can't say. But modelData is null, that's pretty much for sure.

Comment: `private void writeApp(){
  Log.d(TAG+1,modelData.getAppName());//works fine
  Thread mThread = new Thread(){
   public void run(){
    Log.d(TAG+2,modelData.getAppName());//doenst works throws NullPointerException
   }
  };
  mThread.start();
 }`

Comment: Please edit your original question, don't post code to a comment, that's unreadable. Besides, that still doesn't tell us where modelData is declared.

Comment: Is `modelData` declared as `volatile`? While unlikely, this could also be caused by the thread seeing an uninitialised reference before the write is flushed. Also, you should log `modelData == null` and `TAG == null` (if it's a primitive boxing type) in the thread.

Comment: @Inerdial the start of a thread creates a happens-before edge so it cannot be a visibility issue

Comment: Your edit still doesn't show where TAG and modelData are declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you assign modelData to a final local field?

```
private void writeApp(){
    final ModelData data = modelData;
    Log.d(TAG+1,data.getAppName());//works fine
    Thread mThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            Log.d(TAG+2,data.getAppName());//doenst works throws NullPointerException
        }
    };
    mThread.start();
}
```

If `//works fine` still works then `//doesnt work` will now work.

Comment: yes it works.thank you.But i am still confused about how does different thread access main thread variable in standard java?

Comment: There just isn't enough context based on your question.  Are you ever setting the reference to null?

Comment: For instance if you do `writeApp(); modelData = null;`  You will probably get a NPE

Comment: Yes i know it.And i got what you mean with final keyword.That fixed throwing NullPointerException by prevent data to be null and makes it const.Is the standard java behavior proper and have i understood threads wrong? cuz i know if i don't share instance to thread , i can't access it.

Comment: If you ever set modelData to null, then yes it is definitely possible that you will get the NullPointerException.  When accessing it in the anonymous Thread class, you are accessing the globally shared field.  If the field ever changes after myThread was created the run method will see that newely created object (if null)

Answer (score 1):

Are you ever instantiating the Data object?

To me it looks like your problem is just that modelData is probably null, and you trying to call `.getAppName()` on it which would throw a null pointer if modelData is null.

I would not expect it to work correctly on "plain" java if you don't instantiate your Data object either, but it is certainly possible there are some differences that could cause it to work on one, and not the other.

Comment: i am sure that modelData is not null, i can reach it from outside of the thread without any Exception in same method.And i am not having problem with that.I am confused about standard java behavior .How could different thread access main thread mutable even i don't share instance?